# Java - POI : issue while extracting text from doc file

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to extract text from a Word DOC file.

```
ClassLoader classloader =
    org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.class.getClassLoader();
URL res = classloader.getResource(
    "org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/POIFSFileSystem.class");
String path = res.getPath();
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileNameorFilePath));
WordExtractor wordExtractor = new WordExtractor(doc);
return wordExtractor.getText();
```

I am getting this error  :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument: method <init>()V not found
```

at the line : `HWPFDocument docx = new HWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileNameorFilePath));`

How can I fix it?

[UPDATE]
POI dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
        
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1-FINAL</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Fix your classpath, you have Apache POI jars from different versions

Comment: you can see the pom content, I am a bit confused about how to change the poi dependencies to solve the pb. What should I change?

Comment: You have a different version for scratchpad to the rest, fix that to match. And also consider upgrading to something recent + supported!